# Is it possible to show tabs as tabs when in list mode?

Tags: vim

I am trying to show trailing spaces as periods but tabs as tabs in Vim.

Here is the help document I am looking at.

```
'listchars' 'lcs'   string  (default "eol:$")
            global
            {not in Vi}
    Strings to use in 'list' mode and for the |:list| command.  It is a
    comma separated list of string settings.
                            *lcs-tab*
      tab:xy    Two characters to be used to show a tab.  The first
            char is used once.  The second char is repeated to
            fill the space that the tab normally occupies.
            "tab:>-" will show a tab that takes four spaces as
            ">---".  When omitted, a tab is show as ^I.
```

I currently have the following two lines in my `.vimrc` file.

```
exec "set listchars=tab:>-,trail:\uB7,nbsp:~"
set list
```

**What should I replace the characters `>-` with so that tabs will display as ordinary tabs?**

Characters sequences tried and failed:

- Two spaces
- Two spaces with `\` escape before each one
- A tab and a space

When I do the latter, I get an error that looks like this.

```
Error detected while processing /home/hq6/.vimrc:
line  202:
E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:^I
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul's answer reminded me that I was calling `exec` so I might need an extra layer of escaping. I just tried the following and it works.

```
exec "set listchars=tab:\\ \\ ,trail:\uB7,nbsp:~"
set list
```

Answer (score 0):

`:set listchars=tab:\ \ ,eol:$` works for me.

Comment: This does not appear to work with ` exec "set listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:\uB7,nbsp:~"`,  which I think is needed for evaluating the Unicode characters.